# How to perform Exception Handling in Redux for HTTP requests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, error-handling, redux-observable

I am learning react with redux and redux-observable. In particular I am trying to understand how to approach error handling. So far:

1. I have managed to create an redux-observable epic that that responds to a fetch action. Specifically, it makes an ajax request and responds with a success or failure action.

   a. If the ajax request succeeds then the epic triggers a success action with the response data as the payload.

   b. If the request fails then the epic triggers a fail action with the error as the payload.
2. The component checks for the presence of an error state and if it is present then it throws it to a surrounding Error Boundary component.

The problem that I am experiencing with this approach is that the error is remaining in the store state. As an example, assume the following local development environment:

1. React/Redux client using redux-observable epics to make http requests.
2. Rest API server (**NOT STARTED**)

When my React/Redux client makes a request to the Rest API server a network connection error is raised, triggering failure action and resulting in an error state being stored.
I then **START** the Rest API server and try to make the same http request from the React/Redux client. The error from the previous request remains in the store. Consequently, an error notification is displayed.

Subsequently, how do I reset to allow a fresh request with no error? Are there any recommended patterns for error handling with react and redux when using middlewares such as redux-observable or redux-saga?

**Epic**

```js
import { Epic } from 'redux-observable';
import { isActionOf } from 'typesafe-actions';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, filter, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { fetchCoursesAsync } from './actions';
import { RootAction, RootState, Services } from 'ReduxTypes';

export const fetchCoursesRequestAction: Epic<
  RootAction,
  RootAction,
  RootState,
  Services
> = (action$, state$, { courseServices }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(fetchCoursesAsync.request)),
    switchMap(() =>
      courseServices.default.getCourses().pipe(
        map(fetchCoursesAsync.success),
        catchError((error: Error) =>
          of(fetchCoursesAsync.failure({ hasError: true, error: error })),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

**Functional component**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { GridSpacing } from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import Course from '../components/Course/Course';
import { courseModels } from '../redux/features/course';
import { courseSelectors } from '../redux/features/course';
import { fetchCoursesAsync } from '../redux/features/course/actions';
import { RootState } from 'ReduxTypes';

type ErrorReport = { hasError: boolean; error?: Error };
type StateProps = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  courses: courseModels.Course[];
  error: ErrorReport;
};

/**
 * Redix state and dispatch mappings
 */
const dispatchProps = {
  fetchCourses: fetchCoursesAsync.request,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  isLoading: state.courses.isLoadingCourses,
  courses: courseSelectors.getReduxCourses(state.courses),
  error: courseSelectors.getReduxCoursesError(state.courses),
});

/**
 * Component property type definitions
 */
type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & typeof dispatchProps;

/**
 * CourseList component
 */
const CourseList = ({
  courses = [],
  error,
  fetchCourses,
  isLoading,
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  // fetch course action on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCourses();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  if (error && error.hasError && error.error) {
    throw error.error; // notify surrounding Error Boundary 
  }
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: 20, padding: 30 }}>
      {
        <Grid container spacing={2 as GridSpacing} justify="center">
          {courses.map(element => (
            <Grid item key={element.courseID}>
              <Course course={element} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

/**
 * Exports
 */
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  dispatchProps,
)(CourseList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think that I have solved the underlying issue by clearing the error state associated with the fetch when new fetch request is made or a fetch is successful. I have included the reducer code and client component code below. Open to other suggestions....

If the client component detects that an error state exists it renders it. So far, I have found that if the client component throws the error (encapsulated by the error state) it is caught by a surrounding error boundary. However, the next time the component is visited the fetch action does not seem to be raised in the useEffect function. I will have to investigate this further to determine if problem lies somewhere within my ErrorBoundary component....maybe a subsequent separate question.

**Reducer**

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { createReducer } from 'typesafe-actions';

import { fetchCoursesAsync } from './actions';

import { Course } from './model';

/**
 * Error State
 */
type ErrorReport = Readonly<{
  hasError: boolean;
  error: undefined;
}>;
const initialErrorState: ErrorReport = {
  hasError: false,
  error: undefined,
};

const isLoadingCourses = createReducer(false as boolean)
  .handleAction([fetchCoursesAsync.request], () => true)
  .handleAction(
    [fetchCoursesAsync.success, fetchCoursesAsync.failure],
    () => false,
  );

const courses = createReducer([] as Course[]).handleAction(
  fetchCoursesAsync.success,
  (state, action) => action.payload,
);

const error = createReducer(initialErrorState)
  .handleAction(
    [fetchCoursesAsync.request, fetchCoursesAsync.success],
    (state): ErrorReport => ({
      hasError: false,
      error: undefined,
    }),
  )
  .handleAction(
    [fetchCoursesAsync.failure],
    (state, action): ErrorReport => ({
      hasError: action.payload.hasError,
      error: action.payload.error,
    }),
  );

const coursesReducer = combineReducers({
  isLoadingCourses,
  courses,
  error,
});

export default coursesReducer;
export type CoursesState = ReturnType<typeof coursesReducer>;
```

**CourseList**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { GridSpacing } from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import Course from '../components/Course/Course';

import { courseModels } from '../redux/features/course';
import { courseSelectors } from '../redux/features/course';
import { fetchCoursesAsync } from '../redux/features/course/actions';
import { RootState } from 'ReduxTypes';

type ErrorReport = { hasError: boolean; error?: Error };
type StateProps = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  courses: courseModels.Course[];
  error: ErrorReport;
};

/**
 * Redux dispatch and state mappings
 */
const dispatchProps = {
  fetchCourses: fetchCoursesAsync.request,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  isLoading: state.courses.isLoadingCourses,
  courses: courseSelectors.getReduxCourses(state.courses),
  error: courseSelectors.getReduxCoursesError(state.courses),
});

/**
 * Component property type definitions
 */
type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & typeof dispatchProps;

/**
 * CourseList component
 */
const CourseList = ({
  courses = [],
  error,
  fetchCourses,
  isLoading,
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  // fetch course action on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('COURSELIST FETCHING COURSES');
    fetchCourses();
  }, [fetchCourses]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  if (error && error.hasError && error.error) {
    // throw error.error;
    // if throw the error from state then encapsulating error boundary catches and displays
    // however subsequent request actions are not processed by redux-observable action stream
    // needs further investigation and if necessary a subsequent question posted....

    // if render error inside component then redux-observable stream continues
    // to process subsequent actions.
    return <p>{JSON.stringify(error.error, null, 2)}</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: 20, padding: 30 }}>
      {
        <Grid container spacing={2 as GridSpacing} justify="center">
          {courses.map(element => (
            <Grid item key={element.courseID}>
              <Course course={element} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

/**
 * Exports
 */
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  dispatchProps,
)(CourseList);
```